# PE Section Flags

Tags: java, memory, portable-executable

For example Characteristics of section .text is 60000020, seems that is

```
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE  0x00000020
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE   0x20000000
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ  0x40000000
```

How to clearly identify which characteristics hide this field?

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear. You already appear to have found the relevant flags, so what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Michael I said "it seems" it doesn't mean that it is true ... it's just an assumption, to be sure that I'm right I asked: "How to clearly identify which characteristics hide this field?"

Comment: Well, it should all be documented over at MSDN. For example, the [Section Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#section-table-section-headers) documentation links to the [Section Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#section-flags) documentation, and there you can see all the flags.

Answer (score 0):

if 60000020&IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE==IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE mean's 60000020 have 0x20.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).